# Is branding name or application name is same or different. To submit app to the app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

My application got rejected saying that : The seller and company associated with your app does not reflect the name " " in the app or its metadata as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

In Next Step it says your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the brand name. If you have developed this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to addd you to the development team of their apple development account.

But the application belongs to our company only and how can i make the app store to make it live with the metadata we provided.

Can anyone please help how to solve this issue.

And thanks in advance....

Comment: Apple is cracking down on misleading app names and branding. For example if you try and publish an app called "Nike Shoes" but your company is not Nike expect to be rejected. You need to name your app so that it does not reflect some other company.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for replying.Think our company as some xyz group inc and our app name is "ABC". so what should i do to come our app live.

Comment: And also this "ABC" name also belongs to our company only. So what should i do to accept app store my application.

Comment: You may be able to provide paperwork to Apple; company or trademark registration documents for example; but you will need to ask Apple